# gsoap changing response content type in case of 404 error

Tags: http-post, gsoap

I'm using gsoap httppost plugin to implement server that accepts post request.

In case of error I am returning 404 error but the content type is always `text/xml`, however I require content type to be `text/html`

below is code snippet

```
int wildcard_handler(struct soap* soap)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "In wild card handler content_type" << soap->http_content;
    LOGDEBUG(ss.str());

    soap->http_content = "text/html";
    soap_send_empty_response(soap, 404);
    return SOAP_OK;

}
```

but on browser i receive text/xml & error 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [stdsoap2.cpp](https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP/blob/master/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp) in order to return an `text/html` answer you should use :

```
int wildcard_handler(struct soap* soap)
{
    soap_response(soap, SOAP_HTML);
    soap_send(soap, "<HTML>...</HTML>");
    soap_end_send(soap);
    soap_closesock(soap);
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

This will allow you to send an HTML answer but not an error 404.

In order to send 404 and an `text/html` content is possible but it is more complex because it needs to overide the soap->fresponse handler to propagate http error code and SOAP_HTML flag.